# Difference in execution of correlated sub query and in-line view?

Tags: sql

While compare correlated sub query and in-line view. which executes faster?. Can any one explain which is best while consider performance of SQL execution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You seem to be new. If you find a response sufficiently useful to answer your question, it is customary to "tick" the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Views are faster. They query is "pre-optimised" and it can cache your results. This will make the DBMS (in most cases) pull the results from a buffer and not access the hard disk to run the query.
If you index the view you will see even greater performance boosts.

Cheers.